# Script ‒ Move files that match with the records in text file based on parameters

Tags: scripting

What I'm trying to accomplish is to *move files in my directory that match with the records in my text file based on 2 parameters*.

For example I have a record in my text file that reads:

```
SPPARK|10416|3308123|3308123|Uphold|Thelma|1930/05/20||
```

I have a file in my directory that reads:

```
1123_M1123_UPHOLD_M1123_MESSAGE_SPPARK_348642.pdf
```

So if last name `UPHOLD` and 4th field `M1123` match up to my fields in my text file, then I want to move them to a specified directory.

```
for files in test/* ; do
 echo $files | awk -F "_" '{print $3,$4}'
done
```

Comment: Which field of the text file must `4534534` match with? is the lastname always capitalized in the filename?

Comment: The second field, and the last names aren't capitalized in the text file

Comment: @JoshAdams steeldriver asked about the name in the _filename_.

Comment: My bad, thank you, 4th field in the filename and they are always captalized

Comment: Could you please give an example where the data in your file and the parts of the filename match up? Also, could you clarify whether you are looking for files based on the data, or whether you want to _create_ the data from the filenames?  I know your title says you want to move the files, but your loop makes no sense. Also clarify the field numbers, you refer the 4th field of the filename (`M1123`) as the "last name", which confuses me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one. Change "echo" command to cp or mv after testing:

```
for f in samples.txt ; do 
  echo /source/path/*$(cut -d '|' -f 5,2 $f | tr '|'a-z '_'A-Z)*.pdf /destination/path
done
```

I'm sorry, my bad. Thanks @Kusalananda. Please, consider the above answer wrong and try this one instead. Supposing you are filtering on 5-th and 4-th columns it copies files from /src to /dst:

```
awk -F "|" '{system("cp /src/*"toupper($5)"_"$4"*.pdf /dst")}' samples.txt
```

Comment: Thank You definitely what I'm looking, just one question, why does not exist show up at the end, I'm a noob to scripting

Comment: Why are you looping over that single file name?

Comment: Ok this won't work I tried copying, but It won't copy because the original filename is being changed, thus the file doesn't exist, I wish to retain the original file when copying

Comment: `cut -f 5,2` will give you column 2 and column 5, but will not swap the order of them.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this the other way around:

- read and split the text file into fields line-by-line
- match and move the corresponding files

E.G. (assumes `bash` and GNU `mv`):

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

while IFS='|' read -r loc a b c last first d e; do 
  echo mv --no-clobber -t path/to/target/ -- *_"$a"_"${last^^}"_*_*_*_*.pdf
done < file.txt
```

Remove the `echo` once you are satisfied that it is doing what you want

Comment: Ok I'm getting this error when I run it: 0403-011 The specified substitution is not valid for this command.

Comment: @JoshAdams what is your bash version (`bash --version`)? how are you executing the script?

Comment: I'm using korn shell

Comment: @JoshAdams if you **must** do it in a Korn shell, then you will need to modify the upper-casing (setting `typset -u last` and then replacing `${last^^}` by just `$last` should be a fairly portable alternative) and finding a way to do the nullglob - the latter will depend on which exact implementation of ksh you are using IIRC